# Picklist values not showing

Tags: custom-field, picklist

### What I have

A custom picklist field on a custom object and the list has two possible values:
[image]

The FLS on the field is set to visible and editable for the user profile I am testing with.

On the form layout the field properties for the field is not read-only.

I didn't manually edit the metadata, but it looks like this:

```
<fields>
    <fullName>Workflow__c</fullName>
    <description>The input source workflow determines how new leads from this source will be earmarked so that new case records can be started in the correct system workflow.</description>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <inlineHelpText>Select the workflow for new cases from this input source.</inlineHelpText>
    <label>Workflow</label>
    <picklist>
        <picklistValues>
            <fullName>Country</fullName>
            <default>true</default>
        </picklistValues>
        <picklistValues>
            <fullName>Ministry</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </picklistValues>
        <sorted>false</sorted>
    </picklist>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Picklist</type>
</fields>
```

### My problem

All the picklist values are not showing up for selection:

[image]

The default picklist value is also not honoured. That is, when I create a new record the value for the `Workflow__c` field is not populated with the value "Country" as I expected.

Can we fix this?

Comment: Have you got any record types in this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you haven't assigned the picklist to record type. In your custom object, there should be something like:

```
<recordTypes>
    (...)
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Data_Source__c</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>some name</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
</recordTypes>
```